# Timezone changing automatically to 'Chicago' after rebooting CentOS 7

Tags: centos, timezone

I recently switched from CentOS 6 to 7. I've noticed that every time I reboot my OS, it switches my timezone to Chicago (CDT) but I'm in EDT. It is easy enough to update the timezone with `timedatectl set-timezone America/New_York` but it is quite annoying to do this after every reboot. Any ideas?

Based on a similar post I checked my `hwclock`:

```
$ sudo hwclock --show
Tue 01 Aug 2017 10:40:58 AM EDT  -0.344415 seconds
```

So that looks fine.

Comment: What are your ntp settings?

Comment: good question, but from checking that, it doesn't look like my machine is running ntp. I have the machine set to use automatic time/date/zone, but no NTP servers setup that I can tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after digging further into my issue, it turns out that everything on the gnome/centos 7 side is working as expected. This issues is that the CradlePoint LTE modem/router we use at the office for internet connectivity is resolving the wrong timezone... which is a whole other issue for a different board.

So the solution is that I needed to look further up the tree on the networking side before assuming that such a simple feature would be failing on the OS side :-)